# Typescript/Request-Promise: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, request-promise

I have a server endpoint that I want to either return the result of an async request or a promise rejection `Promise.reject('error message')`, however when I add the `Promise.reject` to the function instead of just returning the async request, I get this error:

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ <U>(onFulfill?: (value: any) => U | PromiseLike<U>, onReject?: (error: any) => U | PromiseLike<...' has no compatible call signatures.`

I am confused because `Promise.reject` has a `then` method. Here is the code:

```
const funcThatReturnsPromise = (data) => {
    const validatedData = validateKeyData(data)
    if(validatedData) {
      return request.post({
        url: '/apiurl',
        json: true,
        body: validatedData
      })
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('TESTING rejected')
    }
}

const funcThatDoesWork = ((req, res) => {
    return funcThatReturnsPromise(req.body)
    .then(data => {
       if(data) {
         const theId = data.id
         const fullData = { ...req.body, theId }
       }
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log('ERROR', error)
       res.status(500).send({code: 'unknown', message: error})
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `RequestPromise` is based on `Promise<any>` from Bluebird, but not identical to it, the `funcThatReturnsPromise` really returns the union type `RequestPromise | Promise<never>`, which hasn't got the required call signature for `then` (it has two ones, typed independently, and compiler can't call both at once).

The same problem would arise in the following simple code:

```
const prom = Math.random() > 0.5 ? Promise.resolve(true) : Promise.resolve(0);
// prom has a type Promise<number> | Promise<boolean>
prom.then(data => { const test = 1; }); // error: then() is ambiguous
```

I've found two ways to work with this:

1. (not typesafe) Just assert the rejected promise to be `Promise<any>`:

   ```
   const funcThatReturnsPromise = (data) => {
        const validatedData = validateKeyData(data)
        if(validatedData) {
          return request.post({
            url: '/apiurl',
            json: true,
            body: validatedData
          })
        } else {
          return Promise.reject('TESTING rejected') as Promise<any>
        }
    }
   ```
2. (typesafe) Make a correct typings for both return values. It will be something like this:

   ```
   const funcThatReturnsPromise = (data) => {
       const validatedData = validateKeyData(data)
       if(validatedData) {
         return request.post({
           url: '/apiurl',
           json: true,
           body: validatedData
         }) as Partial<Promise<ResultType>> & Pick<Promise<ResultType>, 'then' | 'catch'>
       } else {
         return Promise.reject('TESTING rejected') as Promise<ResultType>
       }
   }
   ```

where `ResultType` is... well, the `typeof` data we are waiting for.
Note that we can't just assert `request.post({...})` as `Promise<ResultType>`, since `RequestPromise` doesn't provide the full `Promise` API, but we can force the compiler to know that at least methods `then` and `catch` of `Promise` are here (and possibly something else).